# Show message if connection refused on Android

Tags: android, json, http

I'm currently developing an Android application that requires HTTP connection. I'm using a physical device to test my app. If the wireless connection on my device is not turned on and I start the application it will obviously crash telling me "Unfortunately, My Application has stopped."  . And then there's this stack trace telling me the connection to my URL was refused. So far so good. Now, what I need is for my application to not crash when I don't have internet connection on my device, but instead, I want it to show a dialog and keep the application running.
I am also using Json.

Here is part of my code:

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_restaurants, "GET", params);
        System.out.println(json.toString());
        if (json==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else {

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
        }

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    Jrestaurants = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESTAURANTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jrestaurants.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = Jrestaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String description = c.getString("description");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String rating = c.getString("rating");
                        String open = c.getString("open");
                        String close = c.getString("close");
                        double lat = c.getDouble("latitude");
                        double longit = c.getDouble("longitude");

                        Restaurant r = new Restaurant(name, description, address, rating, open, close, lat, longit);
                        //   Restaurant r2 = new Restaurant("Nobori Japanese Restaurant","0364 144 626","Plopilor 57-62 Street","4.2","10:00 am","11:30 pm",46.762555,23.556854);

                        restaurants.add(r.getName());
                        //  restaurants.add(r2.getName());

                        restaurantsMap.put(r.getName(), r);
                        //restaurantsMap.put(r2.getName(),r2);
                    }
                } else {


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

The thing I tried is checking if `json` is null but that does not work. I'm not really sure what and where to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

---

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean internet = netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();

if(internet) {
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_restaurants, "GET", params);
    //....
} else {
    //show dialog
}
```

Comment: What happens excactly?

Comment: Same old `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.2.102 refused`

Comment: Have you asked for the permission in the manifest? Can you show me how you edited the code?

Comment: It didn't work when I put it in my method but I put the code in the `onCreate`  before I execute my task and it works. Thank you sir :D

Comment: It should also work inside your method, just make a reference to the activity's context... but it is usually better inside 'onCreate'.

Answer (score 1):

Make this method in your class:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    return ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

Call this method and execute your asycTask in if condition:

```
if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
    // available network
    new MyTask().execute(""); // like this
} else {
    // no network
}
//<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but i think your code only tells you that you are connected to a network but not if the network has internet connection.

Comment: Yes but i have executed task while network is connected, only
its simple way just determine connection available or not if available call your web service, else show Toast message and dont call web service, you will never get exception